# How do I configure NPM to use the system certificate authorities in CentOS/RHEL?

Tags: linux, npm, certificate, ca

How can I configure NPM to use the system certificate bundle in an Enterprise Linux based OS (CentOS/RedHat/etc)?

Additionally, how can I add a custom certificate to this store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Configuring NPM to use System CAs

For Enterprise Linux-based systems your certificate store is located at `/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem`.

You can configure NPM to globally use this certificate store using:

```
npm config set cafile "/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem" -g
```

### Adding a Root Certificate to System CA Bundle

You can install a custom root certificate using the following commands:

```
> sudo update-ca-trust
```

Copy the `.crt` file you want to add to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/`

ONLY if running a 6.x Enterprise Linux variant run the following command: `sudo update-ca-trust enable`

Finally, for all variants update the bundle: `sudo update-ca-trust extract`